# Throw custom timeout exception

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, try-catch, timeoutexception

I have a Google Apps Script web app ("Web App") that executes as the user, then calls individual functions from another Apps Script project ("API Executable") via the Apps Script API using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` and executes them as me (see [Get user info when someone runs Google Apps Script web app as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972996/get-user-info-when-someone-runs-google-apps-script-web-app-as-me)).

A limitation of this method is that `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` has a 60s timeout, and one of my functions often takes longer than this. The API Executable function finishes running successfully, but the web app throws a timeout exception. I would like to handle this exception by running a second "follow-up" function that finds and returns the URL of the Google Sheet successfully created by the original function. However, I'll need to pass the follow-up function one of the parameters passed to the original function, and it appears I can't do this within a standard try...catch block.

My idea was to throw an exception that contains the needed parameter, but I can't figure out how to throw my own timeout exception; since Google Apps Script is synchronous, there's no way to track how long `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` has been running *while it's running*.

Is there a way to throw your own timeout exception? Or, is there another way I can pass the needed parameter to a function that executes if there's a timeout error?

I tagged Javascript in this post as well since there's a lot of overlap with Google Apps Script and I figured it would improve my chance of connecting with someone who has an answer--hope that's okay. Below is the function I'm using in my web app to call my API Executable functions, in case that's helpful.

EDIT: Based on @TheMaster's comment, I decided to write the script as though parameters passed to `executeAsMe()` WERE being passed to the `catch()` block, to see what happened. I expected an exception regarding the fact the `opt_timeoutFunction` was undefined, but strangely it looks like only the first line of the `catch()` block is even running, and I'm not sure why.

```
function executeAsMe(functionName, paramsArray, opt_timeoutFunction, opt_timeoutParams) {
  try {
    console.log('Using Apps Script API to call function ' + functionName.toString() + ' with parameter(s) ' + paramsArray.toString());

    var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/Mq71nLXJPX95eVDFPW2DJzcB61X_XfA8E:run';

    var payload = JSON.stringify({"function": functionName, "parameters": paramsArray, "devMode": true})

    var params = {method:"POST",
                  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAppsScriptService().getAccessToken()},
                  payload:payload,
                  contentType:"application/json",
                  muteHttpExceptions:true};

    var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(results).response;
    if (jsonResponse == undefined) {
      var jsonResults = undefined;
    } else {
      var jsonResults = jsonResponse.result;
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error = ' + error); // I'm seeing this in the logs...
    console.log('error.indexOf("Timeout") = ' + error.indexOf("Timeout").toString); // ...but not this. It skips straight to the finally block
    if (error.indexOf('Timeout') > 0) { // If error is a timeout error, call follow-up function
      console.log('Using Apps Script API to call follow-up function ' + opt_timeoutFunction.toString() + ' with parameter(s) ' + paramsArray.toString());

      var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/Mq71nLXJPX95eVDFPW2DJzcB61X_XfA8E:run';

      var payload = JSON.stringify({"function": opt_timeoutFunction, "parameters": opt_timeoutParams, "devMode": true})

      var params = {method:"POST",
                    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAppsScriptService().getAccessToken()},
                    payload:payload,
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    muteHttpExceptions:true};

      var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(results).response;
      if (jsonResponse == undefined) {
        var jsonResults = undefined;
      } else {
        var jsonResults = jsonResponse.result;
      }
    }
  } finally {
    console.log('jsonResults = ' + jsonResults);
    return jsonResults;
  }

}
```

Comment: *However, I'll need to pass the follow-up function one of the parameters passed to the original function, and it appears I can't do this within a standard try...catch block.* Why so? All arguments to function should be available in the `catch` block

Comment: @TheMaster I thought the only thing passed to the catch block was ```err```. Oh my gosh I am so excited if I'm wrong!

Comment: *skips straight to the finally block* because that line in the catch block errors out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the '''catch()''' block to throw an exception back to the client side and handle it there.

Google Apps Script:

```
function executeAsMe(functionName, paramsArray) {
  try {
    console.log('Using Apps Script API to call function ' + functionName.toString() + ' with parameter(s) ' + paramsArray.toString());

    var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/Mq71nLXJPX95eVDFPW2DJzcB61X_XfA8E:run';

    var payload = JSON.stringify({"function": functionName, "parameters": paramsArray, "devMode": true})

    var params = {method:"POST",
                  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAppsScriptService().getAccessToken()},
                  payload:payload,
                  contentType:"application/json",
                  muteHttpExceptions:true};

    var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(results).response;
    if (jsonResponse == undefined) {
      var jsonResults = undefined;
    } else {
      var jsonResults = jsonResponse.result;
    }
    return jsonResults;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error = ' + error);
    if (error.toString().indexOf('Timeout') > 0) {
      console.log('Throwing new error');
      throw new Error('timeout');
    } else {
      throw new Error('unknown');
    }
  } finally {
  }
}
```

Client-side Javascript (a simplified version):

```
 function createMcs() {
      var userFolder = getDataFromHtml().userFolder;    

      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(createMcsSuccess)
        .withFailureHandler(createMcsFailure)
        .withUserObject(userFolder)
        .executeAsMe('createMasterCombinedSchedule', [userFolder]);
    }

    function createMcsSuccess(mcsParameter) {
      if (mcsParameter == undefined) {
        simpleErrorModal.style.display = "block"; // A generic error message
      } else {
        document.getElementById("simpleAlertHeaderDiv").innerHTML = 'Master Combined Schedule Created Successfully';
        document.getElementById("simpleAlertBodyDiv").innerHTML = 'Your Master Combined Schedule was created successfully. Click <a href="' + mcsParameter + '" target="_blank">here</a> to view.';
        simpleAlertModal.style.display = "block";
      }
    }

    function createMcsFailure(mcsError, userFolder, counter) { // The exception I threw will activate this function
      if (!counter) { // Added a counter to increment every time checkForCreatedMcs() runs so it doesn't run indefinitely
        var counter = 0;
      }
      if (mcsError.message == 'Error: timeout' && counter < 5) { // If timeout error, wait 10s and look for MCS URL
        window.setTimeout(checkForCreatedMcs(mcsError, userFolder, counter), 10000);
      } else if (mcsError.message == 'Error: timeout' && counter == 5) { // If it hasn't worked after 5 tries, show generic error message
        simpleErrorModal.style.display = "block";
      } else { // For any error that's not a timeout exception, show generic error message
        simpleErrorModal.style.display = "block"; 
      }
    }

    function checkForCreatedMcs(mcsError, userFolder, counter) {
      counter++;
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(checkForCreatedMcsSuccess)
        .withUserObject([mcsError, userFolder, counter])
        .executeAsMe('checkIfMcsExists', [userFolder]); // checkIfMcsExists() is a pre-existing function in my API Executable project I had already used elsewhere      
    }

    function checkForCreatedMcsSuccess(mcsExistsParameter, params) {
      var mcsError = params[0];
      var userFolder = params[1];
      var counter = params[2];
      if (mcsExistsParameter == undefined) { // If function returns undefined, show generic error message
        simpleErrorModal.style.display = "block";
      } else if (mcsExistsParameter == false) { // If function returns false, wait 10s and try again
        createMcsFailure(mcsError, userFolder, counter);
      } else { // If function returns URL, show success modal with link
        document.getElementById("simpleAlertHeaderDiv").innerHTML = 'Master Combined Schedule Created Successfully';
        document.getElementById("simpleAlertBodyDiv").innerHTML = 'Your Master Combined Schedule was created successfully. Click <a href="' + mcsExistsParameter + '" target="_blank">here</a> to view.';
        simpleAlertModal.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

I am sure there has to be a tidier/less complex way to do this, but this worked!