# Google script web app running as me - identify actual user

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, identify

I have a Google Apps Script deployed as a web app.  It is configured to run as me, as it creates and amends events on my calendar and uses a Google sheet of mine as its data store.

There is a requirement that users are NOT required to have a Google (or any other specific type of) account to log on, so I have written a bespoke login function.

The problem I have is reliably identifying the user session.

User properties/cache doesn't work as the user is me for all users.

Is there a way I can identify something unique about the actual user to identify their session?

I understand that web apps run on Google's server and that I have no access to the user's browser so cookies and similar technologies are not an option.

Comment: Hi, have you seen this, it seems you have the same concern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972996/get-user-info-when-someone-runs-google-apps-script-web-app-as-me

Comment: Thanks @Twilight.  I've seen that post before.  My reading of it is that it still requires the user to have a Google account (to make use of the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() ).  There is a requirement that the the user must not need to have a Google account (or any other specifically affiliated login.)